# Power spectral density of noise: what is $\mathcal{N_0}$ in $S_X(f)=\mathcal{N_0}/2$?

Tags: power, antennas, noise

My question is regarding power spectral density of white gaussian noise. It is known that the power spectral density of white gaussian noise is $$S_X(f)= \frac{\mathcal{N_0}}{2}$$

My question is does anyone know what the value of $\mathcal{N}_0$ is ?

Comment: I recommend finding a source that cites your specific formula. They might have a name for your $\mathcal{N}_0$ and provide further insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula $$S_X(f)= \frac{\mathcal{N_0}}{2}$$ the "one-sided" power spectrum density is $$\mathcal{N_0} = k_BT_{eq}$$ where$k_B=1.38 × 10^{-23} \text{ [W/Hz/K] }$ is Boltzmann's constant and $T_{eq}$ is the system temperature.